# indexpath.row restarts at 0 for each section

Tags: ios, tableview

I've got a tableview with a searchbar, indexbar and sections. In my tableview I shows names of airports. When I click on one of the names I get a new view with more information about that person. My problem is that after every section the indexpath.row starts recounting. So if I go to my 3rd section and I select the first row beneath that section, the indexpath.row is 0. So I will always get more information about the names in the first section.

example:

==Section A==

Amsterdam airport1

Amsterdam airport2

Amsterdam airport3

==Section B==

Brussels airport1

Brussels airport2

If I select 'Brussels airport1' in my list, the indexpath.row returns 0. So if I use this in my array, it will act as if I selected 'Amsterdam airport1', because that is the first item in my array.

I have an array called airports that I use to make a Dictionary called airportDictionary for the indexbar. Then when an item is selected I use the indexpath.row to check in my airports array which airport I have selected.

Anyone know how to solve this? If you need more explanation or code, please ask!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSIndexPath` has a something for exactly that - `section` and `row` can be used to distinguish its place.

**Amsterdam airport1**

```
indexPath.section == 0
indexPath.row     == 0
```

**Brussels airport1**

```
indexPath.section == 1
indexPath.row     == 0
```

Comment: So how can I use this indexPath.section to get the right array from my dictionary? Like, is there a method that returns the first array in my dictionary if the indexpath.section = 1. 

Or maybe there's a way to get the header title so I can use objectforkey:headertitle.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. I used `NSString *sectiontitle = [(UILabel*)[self.tableView headerViewForSection:section] text];
            Airport *a = [alphabetizedAirports objectForKey:sectiontitle][indexPath.row];`

Answer (score 2):

You need to organize your data properly. Have an array of arrays. The outer array represents the sections and each inner array represents the rows of that section.

Use `indexPath.section` to access the proper outer array then use the `indexPath.row` to access the proper value within the section array.

Comment: you could use something like this groupBy method (https://github.com/ollieatkinson/ObjectiveCRuby/blob/master/Ruby/NSArray%2BRuby.m#L25) to separate the elements if they come back in a single array which returns a dictionary of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Thats what section is meant for.
For example if you have section 1 has two rows then 
index path has two values i.e 0-0 and 0-1
and then in if the section 2 has two rows again
indexpath has two values again 1-0 and 1-1.